# Anyone know what an <Optional SQL Explain flag> is?

Tags: sql, flags

Does anyone know what an Optional SQL Explain flag is?

Comment: In what context are you asking this question?  Database type?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talkin about the -explain flag in [Oracle SQLJ](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96655/transopt.htm#1004083)? :-

> -explain
>
> Flag to request "cause" and "action" information to be displayed with translator error messages.